# Using data from response in react-admin component

Tags: react-admin

I have a react-admin based app.
API in my server has been changed and some data for my component is coming from another endpoint (but chunk from the first one as early).
I have difficulties with using this new-way-got data in my old component.

Is there any way to use data in arComponent from some array with data except the source? Maybe there is a possibility in react-admin to use data from one resource ("firstResource") in the child-component to `<Resource name="secondResource" ... />` if there are no references in "secondResource" to data from "firstResource"?

Answer (score 0):

The way is to use prop `record` in raComponents. It overrides default `RecordContext`.